# What's the difference between `type A<T> = T[]` and `type B<T> = [T]`

Tags: arrays, typescript, generics, union

Please see the minimum TypeScript generic mapped type code below:

```js
type A<T> = T[]
type B<T> = [T]

type ResultA = A<1 | 2 | 3>
// => type ResultA = (1 | 2 | 3)[]

type ResultB = B<1 | 2 | 3>
// => type ResultB = [1 | 2 | 3]
```

I have two generic mapped type, one returned `T[]`, the other one returned `[T]`, if I pass a union into it, it will resolve difference format.

`(1 | 2 | 3)[]` and `[1 | 2 | 3]`

What's the difference of these two? Which one should I use?

Comment: They're not both arrays, the second is a [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple).

Comment: My bad, you answered my question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one `[T]` only accept 1 item, the other accept unlimited.

E.g: `[string]` only accept `['a']`, not `['a', 'b']`, but `string[]` does